# Karate API , 2 different responses matching

Tags: api, cucumber, karate

I have the following scenario and I want the first or second response to match ( *def first or *def second). Either response is fine. The following isn't working for me.  Can you please help?

Scenario: A

```
Given path 'api/..../0.1/..../availability'
* def futureDate = Java.type('uk.co.vw.api.StringUtil').getFutureDate()
* def first = {"available":'#boolean',"collection":'#boolean',"date":#(futureDate),"lift":'#boolean',"bookingAvailability":'#array',"times":'#array',"loan":'#boolean',"delivery":'#boolean' }
* def second = {"code": "#string","message": "#string"}
  And params {dealerNumber: '00111', date: #(futureDate), serviceCodes: 'MIN:1.4,OER:0.85', mot: 0, postcode: "W2", waitingjob: 0 }
When method get
Then status 200
  And match response contains any (first, second)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential fixes.

The value of date is set as the variable futureDate. You have is written like this `#(futureDate)` when it should be like this `'#(futureDate)'`

You could try this as the assert

```
And match response[*] contains (second)
   And match response[*] contains (first)
```